# Join pandas tables, keeping one index

Tags: python, join, pandas

What I want to do is join two dataframes on columns and keep the index of one of them (but the index is unrelated to whether I join them or not).

For example, if `df1` is the dataframe that has certain timestamps as its index that I would like to keep, then to join with `df2` on the 'key' column, my expected code would be

```
df3 = pd.merge(df1, df2, on='key', left_index=True)
```

I would then expect df3 to have all rows of df1 and df2 where `df3[key] == df1[key] == df2[key]` and `df3[key].index == df1[key].index`.

However, this is not the case. In fact, you find that the index of `df3` is actually the index of `df2`. The reverse is true for `right_index=True`.

I've considered submitting a bug report, but rereading the documentation leads me to believe that (while completely counter intuitive) this may not be incorrect behavior.

What *is* the proper way to join two tables, keeping one of the indices?

EDIT:

I am doing an inner join on 'key'. That is not the issue. The issue is that I want the resulting rows to have the index of one of the dataframes.

For example, if I have the following sets of data in two dataframes:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame(np.arange(4).reshape(2,2))
df2 = pd.DataFrame(np.arange(4).reshape(2,2), columns=[0,2])
df2.index = df2.index.map(lambda x: x + 10)
```

That is,

```
>>> df1
   0  1
0  0  1
1  2  3
>>> df2
    0  2
10  0  1
11  2  3
```

I can run `pd.merge(df1, df2, on=0)` which (as expected) yields

```
>>> pd.merge(df1,df2,on=0)
   0  1  2
0  0  1  1
1  2  3  3
```

Notice, however, that `df2` has a different index. In my actual data, this is timestamp data that I want to keep. It isn't used in the joining at all, but it *does* need to persist. I *could* just add a column to `df2` to keep it around, but that isn't what I want to do. :)

What I would like is to do something like `pd.merge(df1, df2, on=0, right_index=True)` and receive:

```
    0  1  2
10  0  1  1
11  2  3  3
```

However, I actually get the ***opposite*** of this:

```
>>> pd.merge(df1,df2,on=0,right_index=True)
   0  1  2
0  0  1  1
1  2  3  3
```

while reversing them inexplicably works.

```
>>> pd.merge(df1,df2,on=0,left_index=True)
    0  1  2
10  0  1  1
11  2  3  3
```

Comment: Joining the tables really depends on the data, there is not a *single* proper way to join all the tables with *one* universal command. It comes down to what are the two DF you're working with, and what is the output you're wanting. Can you include some data that you're working with, and compare the output you're getting with the expected?

Answer (score 1):

I think what your looking for is akin to Full Outer Join in SQL, in which case I think the following would work:

```
df3 = pd.merge(df1, df2, on='key', how='outer')
```

As for keeping just one index, that should be done automatically in this case now that outer join is keeping all keys.

Using your example:

```
In [4]: df1['key'] = df1.index

In [5]: df2['key'] = df2.index

In [6]: df3 = pd.merge(df1, df2, on='key', how='outer')

In [7]: df3
Out[7]:
   0_x   1  key  0_y   2
0    0   1    0  NaN NaN
1    2   3    1  NaN NaN
2  NaN NaN   10    0   1
3  NaN NaN   11    2   3
```

So in this case a new index is created, but could be re-assigned the original values from 'key' if desired.